# How to access localised resources in an .ashx file?

Tags: asp.net, localization, httphandler, asp.net-4.0, ashx

I have an ashx file which returns a localised message. This is called from an Ajax request. I need to access the Asp.net ResourceManager in the ashx file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following code worked for me.

```
HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("classKey", "resourceKey") as string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Any resources in the app should be accessible under the Resources namespace.

For a resource file called LocalMessages.en.resx:

```
ReturnMsg = Resources.LocalMessages.MyAjaxMessage;
```

For intellisense to work, make sure app has been compiled once to create the Resources objects from resx files.